# authenticated access to Firebase REST API within cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access the firebase REST API from a cloud function, using the built-in `functions.config().firebase` object (my use case is a shallow query).

```
const { credential } = functions.config().firebase;
credential.getAccessToken().then( ({ access_token }) => {
  // use access_token as auth param to query the REST API
});
```

When I use the returned `access_token` as the `auth parameter` in the REST API, I get the `could not parse auth token error`. Is there a way of generating there a valid auth token without exposing in the config the database secret ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a correct way of generating an authentication token, but that with this token, one need to use an `access_token` param instead of the documented `auth` one.